# mod_rewrite help - GET request

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble with what should be a simple mod_rewrite.  I want to convert the following URL:

```
http://example.com/c/c0001
```

to

```
http://example.com/c/index.html?c=c0001
```

I've tried for the life of me and cannot get the rewrite to work.  I know htaccess is being read as my trial attempts are yielding different results, but nothing to get the result I want.  Some examples of what I've tried:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteRule (.*) index.html?c=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.html?c=$1
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+) index.html?c=$1 [L]
```

and many other iterations.  Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Comment: Will it always be prefixed with `/c/`?

Comment: I'd like to segment this particular function into a different directory.  I'll have other html files on the root example.com domain and these are for a specific purpose.  The index.html file itself will also sit in the c directory.That being said, the GET request does not need to start with a c0001.  It could be anything - c0002, RandomLetters, etc.

Comment: Does your .htaccess file live in the `c` directory as well?

Comment: Yes it does. The .htaccess file in my root directory is blank

Comment: Hi Jason - any thoughts on this? Still not able to get this to work

Comment: No. I'm still confused about your current architecture and desired goal.

Comment: index.html sits in example.com/c/  This file requires a GET request to operate correctly.  We'd like to essentially redirect http://example.com/c/xyz into http://example.com/c/index.html?c=xzy

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule c/(.+) index.html?c=$1 [L]
```

I would encourage you to be more specific though, for example if `c` is always in the format `c####` and optionally allowing for the trailing slash.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule c/(c\d+)/? index.html?c=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried this: RewriteRule (.+) index.html?c=$1 [L]  Unfortunately it does not appear to be passing the GET variables to the script.